# Server name on virtual host not working

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, frameworks

please i need your help. I am working on a zend framework 2 project, the project's name in Wamp/www folder is pizza.
i tried to configure a virtual host on hosts file,httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf to work with this project url: pizza.local/

instead of this: localhost:8080/pizza/public/

but something is not ght with my configuration.
note that I am using localhost:8080 not localhost.

Please help me to find what I did wrong. Here's my files:

httpd.conf:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/pizza/public"
    ServerName pizza.local
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/pizza/public">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts file:

```
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1   pizza.local
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using this VHOST on port 8080. You need to mention in URL as below.

```
http://pizza.local:8080/
```